# Use multiple service in same controller angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to use multiple service in same controller. I can achieve with different service as mentioned below but it performs only one service

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<H1>Random Text is:</H1>

<div>{{myRandom}}</div>

<p>MuyLocation:: {{myLocation}}.</p>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location) {
  $http.get("http://www.randomtext.me/api/").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myRandom = response.data.text_out;
      $scope.myLocation= $location.absUrl();
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

BUT, i want to use both service in same controller as mentioned below

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location) {

  $http.get("welcome.htm").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
      $scope.myUrl = $location.absUrl();
  });
});
```

So How can we perform both services in same controller.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have already solved your own problem and answered your question. The last snippet is the answer and it will work correctly

Comment: Have you got an error message ? I agree with Umair, your last snippet must works.
But if you minified js, try to declare your controller with array like this : 
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) { .. }]);
In some case minification can cause issue with DI

Comment: I have tried to edit  with http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_services_http but it not works.

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: @Silvinus, please check my updated question...

Comment: I'm really sorry, but your updated code works (https://plnkr.co/edit/uaaBAqx1VMcciVMwO9e9?p=preview). What is the expected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solved your problem with promise chaining.

```
$http.get("http://www.randomtext.me/api/").then(function success(response) { 
 return $q.resolve(response);
 }, function error() {
 return $http.get("welcome.htm");
}).then(function success(response) { 
  $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
  $scope.myUrl = $location.absUrl();
});
```

If call to randomapi failed, so fetch welcome.html.